# How create a grid system with max of rows equal to 8

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to create a grid system as an example of the image.
the max of lines is 8;
the cell number is variable, it can be 12, 20,100, etc.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF4cU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set:

*(Usefull ressource:  for you : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ & https://gridbyexample.com/ )*

- a grid template of 8 rows ,
- then a template  with auto-fill (or auto-fit)  for the columns
- finally set the grid to fill columns by columns:

example

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(8em;, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;/* optionnal */
  gap:2px;
}


/* see the div */

body {
  counter-reset: divs;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display:flex;
}

div:before {
font-size:calc(12px + 3vw) ;margin:auto;
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```